# Segfaulting when using setjmp longjmp

Tags: c++, signals, setjmp

I have this school project and it is about using setjmp and longjmp to do imprecise calculations. The program starts a timer that will signal a signal handler.

Before the timer expires, there is some iterative calculation(for demo purposes, just a loop doing nothing useful). At the beginning of this loop there is a setjmp call, and in the signal handler there is a longjmp call. This basically forces the loop to stop mid calculation and run the signal handler where it calls longjmp.

The problem I am having is that whenever the calculation portion is very short, I seem to segfault fairly consistently, however when the calculation portion is long(inner loop has many iterations), it runs just fine(have not run into a segfault yet). Obviously the segfault must be occuring in the areas surrounding that calculation section, but I cannot figure out where it is coming from as debugging changes things as does using print statements.

Here is the code I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

jmp_buf env;


static void usr_timer_tick(int signal)
{
    if(signal == SIGALRM)
    {
        longjmp(env, 1);
    }
}


/*Program Description
 * This program first sets up the timer to signal usr_timer_tick
 * every 1 second on the SIGALRM signal. It then proceeds to do an iterated calculation three times.
 * An infinite loop calls setjmp and when 0 is returned, continues doing
 * a calculation on temp. After an iteration is complete, the result of
 * the iteration is saved into finalResult after blocking SIGALRM to
 * make the saving of the result atomic.
 *
 * Once the signal handler(usr_timer_tick) is triggered, it calls longjmp which forces
 * setjmp to return a non-zero value, which causes the main function to break out
 * of the infinite loop and start a new calculation...this is done a total of 3
 * times for demonstration purposes.
 */
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    //init timer using setitimer..real mode
    int which = ITIMER_REAL;
    struct itimerval value;
    struct sigaction sact;
    sigset_t newmask, oldmask;
    sigemptyset( &newmask );
    sigemptyset( &oldmask );
    sigaddset(&newmask, SIGALRM);

    sact.sa_flags = 0;
    sact.sa_handler = usr_timer_tick;
    sigaction( SIGALRM, &sact, NULL );
//    value.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;        /* One second */
//    value.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
//    value.it_value.tv_sec = 1;           /* One second */
//    value.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
//
//    setitimer(which, &value, NULL);



    double finalResult = 0;
    int loopcount = 0;
    double tempResult = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        loopcount = 0;


            std::cout << "Run " << j << " begin loop "
            << loopcount << "\n";


            if(setjmp(env) == 0)
            {   //timer not hit yet

                //sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &newmask, NULL);
                value.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;        /* One second */
                value.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
                value.it_value.tv_sec = 1;           /* One second */
                value.it_value.tv_usec = 0;

                setitimer(which, &value, NULL);

                //sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &oldmask, NULL);
                for(;;)
                {
                    //Do some random calculations
                    for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                    {
                        tempResult = tempResult + .001;
                    }

                    //block signal from arriving and save to finalResult
                    if(sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &newmask, NULL) < 0) exit(-1);
                    finalResult = tempResult;
                    std::cout << "Run " << j << " complete loop "
                        << loopcount << " result = " << finalResult<< "\n";
                    loopcount++;
                    if(sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &oldmask, NULL)< 0) exit(errno);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //timer signal arrived, print the final result and get out of loop
                std::cout << "***Run " << j << " killed on loop "
                        << loopcount << " result = "<< finalResult << "\n";
                sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &oldmask, NULL);
                //break;
            }



    }
    return 0;
}
```

I understand some of you may not agree that longjmp should be used in a signal handler, but this is the way my professor said to do it. Also, it should be noted that I do unblock SIGALRM after the longjmp is called(see else statement of main).

Looking at dmesg I get:

```
 [121395.233842] cppapplication_[17397]: 
segfault at 2 ip b74656f6 sp bfbb5abc 
error 6 in libc-2.12.1.so[b743b000+157000
```

]

Comment: How about using debugger to find where is segfaults ? And what are values of important variables ?

Comment: I am using netbeans which is using gdb debugger. Whenever I run in debug mode, it never segfaults, can't figure out why. Only segfaults in run mode.

Comment: I think you have mismatched braces.  Please fix braces and indentation.

Comment: `newmask` and `oldmask` seem to be switched. Enabling the signal when it should be disabled, or so it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use ´longjmp´ to exit from an asynchronous event like a timer. It is only designed to save and restore registers and the stack pointer that are saved by the normal calling-convention.

Side note: Consider using the `volatile` keyword on your local variables, as specified in 7.13.2.1:

> All accessible objects have values,
>   and all other components of the
>   abstract machine have state, as of
>   the time the `longjmp` function was
>   called, except that the values of
>   objects of automatic storage duration
>   that are local to the function
>   containing the invocation of the
>   corresponding `setjmp` macro that do not
>   have **volatile**-qualified type and have
>   been changed between the `setjmp`
>   invocation and `longjmp` call are
>   indeterminate.

Answer (score 0):

Your signal handler is going to call `longjmp`, so the jump target had better be valid.  That means, call `setjmp` first, then `sigaction` and `setitimer`.

Comment: Agreed, but the timer is set to 1 second, so setjmp is definately going to run first =p. I should probly edit it to follow what you are saying though, thx.

Comment: @user623879: And what happens if `setjmp` is running (again) when `longjmp` is called?  You need to prevent that, and calling `setjmp` before setting up the signal (and then NOT calling it when the signal is unmasked) is the surest way to do so.

Comment: I tried what you said. Code is updated above. Basically I ensure signal handle will never interrupt setjmp by manually resetting the timer with setitimer. I still get segfault though...still no segfault in debug mode though..perplexing. I seem to get this error now sometimes:Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-lookup.c: 725: _dl_lookup_symbol_x: Assertion `version == ((void *)0) || (flags & ~(DL_LOOKUP_ADD_DEPENDENCY | DL_LOOKUP_GSCOPE_LOCK)) == 0' failed!